# android If else statements

Tags: java, android

So my issue is, I get a wierd sound problem (it repeats the hit sound really fast) when I use an if statement to determine if I hit the monster and lived or if I hit the monster and died. Using classic mario logic, if I land on top I live, if not then I die. I didn't have a problem until I added two different if statements. If you need more info let me know. I think my problem is how I am using the if statement.

```
private void checkGhostCollisions() {
    int len = ghosts.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Ghost ghost = ghosts.get(i);
        if (hero.position.y < ghost.position.y) {
            if (OverlapTester.overlapRectangles(ghost.bounds, hero.bounds))
                hero.hitGhost();
                listener.hit();
        } else {
        if(hero.position.y > ghost.position.y) 
             if (OverlapTester.overlapRectangles(hero.bounds, ghost.bounds)) {
                 hero.hitGhostJump();
                 listener.jump();
            break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is hero.position == ghost.position ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
if (hero.position.y < ghost.position.y) {
    if (OverlapTester.overlapRectangles(ghost.bounds, hero.bounds))
        hero.hitGhost();
        listener.hit();
}
```

Note the lack of braces for the *inner* `if` statement, meaning that if the first `if` condition is satisfied, `listener.hit()` is *always* called. I suspect you meant:

```
if (hero.position.y < ghost.position.y) {
    if (OverlapTester.overlapRectangles(ghost.bounds, hero.bounds)) {
        hero.hitGhost();
        listener.hit();
    }
}
```

Two lessons to learn from this:

- Always indent your code properly, and get your IDE to indent it for you if you get confused.
- If you *always* use braces with `if` blocks, it reduces the opportunity for this kind of thing to occur.

EDIT: Note that the inner `if` condition in each case is the same, which means you could simplify this code to:

```
if (OverlapTester.overlapRectangles(hero.bounds, ghost.bounds)) {
    if (hero.position.y < ghost.position.y) {
        hero.hitGhost();
        listener.hit();
    } else {
        hero.hitGhostJump();
        listener.jump();
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that this does slightly change the case where `hero.position.y` is exactly the same as `ghost.position.y` - you should consider what you want to happen in that case.

Comment: now it ignores "if(hero.position.y > ghost.position.y) {
           if (OverlapTester.overlapRectangles(hero.bounds, ghost.bounds)) {
               hero.hitGhostJump();
               listener.jump();"

Comment: @user1449547: Well it's not immediately clear to me exactly what you *do* want to happen in each case... you've effectively got 4 possibilities here. What do you want to happen in each case?